# SQL Connection Error 25 in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Using the following connection string I keep getting the dreaded error 25:

> Cannot connect to SQL Server because connection string is not valid

Here is my connection string:

```
connString = @"Data Source=\\10.23.1.3\vadtcdc3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;User Id = test;Password=test";
```

I'm using VS 2010, MS SQL 2005 standard version, remote access is on, and both Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled. I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient` and I've tried the connection string with and without the @ symbol. After researching many help sites I still haven't come up with an answer.

The connection string works in a VB application, just not in the C# application. In the VB application I'm using the web.config file to specify a user name for access to the server. Is this required for the connection in C#? I'm pretty much at a loss as what to do next...

Comment: remove first "\\" from DataSource and see if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the backslashes before the IP address.

For reference, see [Connection strings for SQL Server 2005](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p1).

Assuming `vadtcdc3` is your instance name, your connection string should be:

```
connString = @"Data Source=10.23.1.3\vadtcdc3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;User Id = test;Password=test";
```

If your database is set up as the default instance, just use:

```
connString = @"Data Source=10.23.1.3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;User Id = test;Password=test";
```

Comment: Did that - no luck . . . Also got rid of the @ symbol - no luck there either . . .

Comment: I am assuming that `vadtcdc3` is your instance name. Can you connect using SSMS using `10.23.1.3\vadtcdc3` as the server name?

Answer (score 0):

is vadtcdc3 the name of your instance?

```
connString = "Server=10.23.1.3\vadtcdc3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;User Id = test;Password=test";
```

Comment: Yes . . . Tried using just the IP address and just the server name vadtcdc3 and that didn't work . . . What is frustrating is that it does work in VB . . .

Comment: is 10.23.1.3 the IP of vadtcdc3? If yes you dont need both of them, just one. try Server=10.23.1.3 only

Comment: That got me to error 40 - named pipes provider error . . . Checked on server and it appears that named pipes is working . . .

Comment: so yo uare on the right track. at least you are reaching the server. You need to configure your sql server to enable named pipes: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
connString = "Data Source=10.23.1.3\\vadtcdc3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;User Id = test;Password=test";
```

Comment: give us the setup of your clients. where is your client located? where is the database server located? is it in the local network? is it located on the WAN?

Answer (score 0):

What type of authentication are you using? If you're using SQL Authentication, you have to specify that the credentials are in your string:

```
Integrated Security = false;
```

So it would look something like:

```
connString = "Data Source=10.23.1.3\\vadtcdc3;Initial Catalog=VADTC;Integrated Security = false;User Id = test;Password=test";
```